# How to remove Admin Menu Bar being Displayed on front-end Event Info Page (CiviCRM 5.12.0)?

Tags: civievent

On the front-end of our site, we have an Event Info page. For some reason, it is now displaying the Admin Menu Bar. We are running CiviCRM 5.12.0 so the patch at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/790 has already been applied. How do we turn it off / hid it?

Comment: in case this is CMS specific you might want to mention what you are using

Comment: Our site is a Joomla based site.